# JavaScript button can only be clicked once with selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I am trying to use Selenium with JUnit and I am having trouble completing my tests because it seems like my button execution is only occurring once. here's some of the code:

```
    JQueryUITab navTab = new JQueryUITab(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("nav ul.tabs")));

    try {
        navTab.selectTab("Tab1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        navTab.selectTab("Tab2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print(navTab.getSelectedTab());
```

the console print out will read `"Tab1"`. this JQueryUITab object is a custom object. here are the inner workings:

```
public String getSelectedTab() {
    List<WebElement> tabs = jQueryUITab.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.tab"));
    for (WebElement tab : tabs) {
        if (tab.getAttribute("class").equals("tab selected")) {
            return tab.getText();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void selectTab(String tabName) throws Exception {
    boolean found = false;
    List<WebElement> tabs = jQueryUITab.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.tab"));

    for (WebElement tab : tabs) {
        if(tabName.equals(tab.getText().toString())) {
            tab.click();
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find tab '" + tabName + "'");
    }
}
```

There are no exceptions thrown. At least pertaining before or at this part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple problems wrong with my implementation. Firstly, it could have been improved by selecting not the `li.tab` object, but the `a` class inside of it. From there, there were 2 solutions that worked for me. First was using

```
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

and the second (imho more elegant solution) was to get the instance of the selenium driver object controlling the object and then get it to execute the command to click the tab. Here's the full corrected method.

```
    public void selectTab(String tabName) throws Exception {
        boolean found = false;
        List<WebElement> tabs = jQueryUITab.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.tab a"));
        for (WebElement tab : tabs) {
            if(tabName.equals(tab.getText().toString())) {              
//              tab.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                WrapsDriver wrappedElement = (WrapsDriver) jQueryUITab;
                JavascriptExecutor driver = (JavascriptExecutor) wrappedElement.getWrappedDriver();
                driver.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", tab);          
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            throw new Exception("Could not find tab '" + tabName + "'");
        }
    }
```